# UITableView reload section while viewing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

After pressing a button on one of my custom TableViewCells I would like to hide/unhide an image on other custom TableViewCells. My cells are ordered in sections.

The changes take effect if I press the button, switch to another view and then come back to my TableView. I would like the changes to appear right away without needing to switch views.

My code:

```
        let otherCellIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        let otherCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: oldIndexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        otherCell.hideImage()

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        currentCell.showImage()

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.reloadSections([otherCellIndexPath,indexPath], with: .none)
        tableView.endUpdates()
```

What am I missing?
(using Xcode 8 b6, Swift 3)

Comment: did you try `tableview.reloadData()`?

Comment: just remove object from array which one you want to hide & reload your tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid calling cellForRow in my code. Instead I maintain a dictionary for state of each cell like

```
var dictSection0 = [["ImageName" : "SampleImageSection0Row0","hidden":true],["ImageName" : "SampleImageSection0Row1","hidden":false]]

var dictSection1 = [["ImageName" : "SampleImageSection1Row0","hidden":true],["ImageName" : "SampleImageSection1Row1","hidden":false]]
var tableDataModel = [dictSection0,dictSection1]
```

On the button tap I would modify the dictionary. In the above case setting hidden to true for row 1 of section 0

```
var rowDict = tableDataModel[0][1]
rowDict["hidden"] = true
```

and then reload the entire table (or a part of it like you are doing) to reflect the changes.

in the cellForRow atIndexPath method this dictionary is used to show/hide the image in the cell.

```
var rowData = tableDataModel[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
let tableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
tableCell.imageView.hidden = rowDict["hidden"]
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Manali suggest should do , calling tableView.reloadSections triggers a series calls on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` , inside that method, the dequeued cell MAY NOT be the exact same object as the one you get by calling `cellForRow` , the right way is to store the information about hiding/unhiding , and show/hide the image inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`